# Aggregating Different Column Values with Another Common Field

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables, movies (id, score) and casts (cast_id, movie_id). I need to create a view to see pairs of cast_id's that have been in at least 3 movies together with an average score of at least 50. I have not been able to figure out the necessary select statement. This is what I have that doesn't work:

```
SELECT cast_id as cast_member_id1, cast_id as cast_member_id2, 
count(*) as movie_count, avg(score) as average_movie_score 
FROM cast c INNER JOIN movies on movies.id = c.movie_id 
GROUP BY cast_member_id1, cast_member_id2 
HAVING cast_member_id1 < cast_member_id2 AND count(*) >= 3 
AND avg(score) >= 50 
ORDER BY avg(score) LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing about these three lines for a moment:

```
SELECT cast_id as cast_member_id1, cast_id as cast_member_id2
.  
FROM cast c ...
.
HAVING cast_member_id1 < cast_member_id2
```

It is selecting a column from cast twice, and then comparing it to itself. The HAVING is never true.

You need to start from a better place, to end up where you want. Try it with 2 "copies" of `cast`.

Something like:

```
SELECT c1.cast_id as cast_member_id1, c2.cast_id as cast_member_id2
.
FROM cast c1, cast c2 .....
.
.
```

And of course you only want to "join" the cast members together if they are in the same movie.

I cannot guarantee this alone will fix the query. But it does put you in a better starting place.